# Tibco Spotfire Sum Hourly Records into Daily with a day start at 10:00

Tags: spotfire

I have hourly data that I need to sum by date, but my sum range for each day should start at 10:00am.

What function should be used in Spotfire?

Comment: layout improved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insert a calculated column for the modified date, then you can sum data based on that.

Expression can be e.g.:
`DateAdd('day',If(Hour([date])>=10, 0,  -1),cast([date] as Date))`

[image]

Comment: @Rookie: glad it helped, if it solved your problem please consider accepting it (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).